# perl-rename - What is the difference between /g' and /'?

Tags: regular-expression

I want to replace all dashes in all `.txt`-files with spaces.

Fortunately, I ultimately found using

```
perl-rename  's/[-]/ /g' *.txt
```

does what I want. But before that, a few minutes of search and t&e went by, as I thought `perl-rename  's/[-]/ /' *.txt` would do the trick. But it does not, as it only removes the very first dash in a filename. Why?

Also, a related meta question: where on earth do I find a good guide on `perl-rename`?

Comment: Most often it will be used with [perlre - Perl regular expressions](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html). You may also find [www.regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) useful.

Comment: @steeldriver This is *it*! Thank you so much. I love you now.

Comment: I think this question might be related to
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20833345).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well `g` stands for global which means that you will replace each non-overlapping match of the pattern that you specifiy.
So

```
perl-rename  's/[-]/ /g' *.txt
```

will replace each occurrence of `-` with a space.